# In aws log i found this

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, nginx

2018/07/06 19:38:08 [error] 21686#0: *2 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.31.20.230, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8081/", host: "node-express-env.vi2kf6fhhd.ap-south-1.elasticbeanstalk.com"

Answer (score 1):

It means that the port is not working. Try ping http://127.0.0.1:8081/ if it giving error means then check your service is running or not if it is runninng then edit inbound ports in aws console.